# Is nailing a double top plate from the bottom to the top bad?

Tags: framing, load-bearing

In my post history I have detailed my project which is essentially replacing a top and bottom plate of a double top plate due to termite damage. I have my top plate in and am having difficulty nailing from the top due to the roof.

It would be a lot easier to nail from the bottom to the top to join the two plates together especially since I can get my nail gun in there.

Is it 'bad' to nail from the bottom to the top versus the other way around?

Comment: I don't think so.  Nailing from the top is usually easy, you are nailing down.  Old school done with hammers.  From the bottom, the top needs to be held/hold/clamp down, so the nails do not push it up.  From your history, a roof does a good job with holding it down.

Comment: Should be no issue; the nails aren't there to keep the top plates from lifting, they're there to keep them stacked vertically instead of shifting laterally.  Nails inserted from below do just as good a job at that.  If it's more convenient, have at it.

Answer (score 0):

Made a comment into answer

`Nailing from the top is usually easy, you are nailing down. Old school done with hammers. From the bottom, the top needs to be held/hold/clamp down, so the nails do not push it up. From your history, a roof does a good job with holding it down`

Comment Posted by @crip659

[Is nailing a double top plate from the bottom to the top bad?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/275962/is-nailing-a-double-top-plate-from-the-bottom-to-the-top-bad/275966?noredirect=1#)

Comment: Please see the help center page for how to reference work written by others: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/referencing